# Is it possible to run ServiceStack generated services on separate ports?

Tags: c#, servicestack

We are creating an application and would like to build into our application some services to perform internal admin tasks on the application, i.e., services our clients, or anyone else, cannot access.  Is it possible to have any services on a separate port so they can be locked down by the firewall?  If not, what is the best way to lock down services without having to create a separate application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ServiceStack Services only have one AppHost which can only be hosted on a single port per App Domain. You would need to run multiple instances with different configurations to have them run on multiple ports.

### [Restricting Services](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Restricting-Services)

You can instead take advantage of the [Restrict Attributes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Restricting-Services) which will let you restrict access of Services by any combination of [RequestAttributes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/RequestAttributes.cs) with useful properties for common scenarios, e.g. you can restrict access to Services by annotating Request DTO's with:

```
[Restrict(LocalhostOnly = true)]
public class OnlyAvailableToLocalRequests { }
```

Or Internal Network's with:

```
[Restrict(InternalOnly = true)]
public class OnlyAvailableToLocalRequests { }
```

Comment: Thanks for the information.  How does the `Restrict` attribute work?  Does it rely on IP addresses?

Comment: @TortillaCurtain it compares the Request's UserHostAddress with the registered Network Interfaces on the ServiceStack Host.